# Azure Site Recovery, powershell - reprotect - No appliance found with the name 'ApplName'

Tags: azure, powershell, recovery

I have set up Azure Site Recovery from Vmware to Azure. I have an ASR appliance in Vmware.
I am trying to automate failovers and failback with powershell.

I am able to do test failovers and cleanups.
The full failover is a bit more challenging. There are more steps.

FAILOVER - failover, commit, re-protect (RecoveryToPrimary).

FAILBACK - PlannedFailover, Commit, re-protect (oPrimaryToRecoveryT).

I am stuck on the re-protect steps. here is my code.

#Variables

```
$VaultName = "rsv-myvault"
$ASRRecoveryPlanName = "PLAN-TST-TEST"
$TestFailoverVNetName = "myVnett"
$resourceGroupname = "MyRG"
$ApplianceName = "L1MGMT-ASR01"
$StorageAccountId = "mystore9cc4"
$Datastorename = "L1DS-SRV02"
$vmname = "myVM"
```

#Connect

```
Connect-AzAccount
$subID = (Get-AzSubscription).id

Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subID
$vault = Get-AzRecoveryServicesVault -Name $VaultName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName 
Set-AzRecoveryServicesAsrVaultContext -Vault $vault
```

#Network, fabric, container, replicatedItem

```
$TFOVnet = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $TestFailoverVNetName
$TFONetwork = $TFOVnet.Id
$asrfabric = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrFabric

$PrimaryProtContainer = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainer -Fabric $asrfabric
$rpi = Get-AzRecoveryServicesAsrReplicationProtectedItem  -ProtectionContainer $PrimaryProtContainer -friendlyName $vmname
```

#FAILOVER:

```
$TFOJobUnPlan = Start-AzRecoveryServicesAsrUnplannedFailoverJob -ReplicationProtectedItem $rpi -Direction PrimaryToRecovery -Confirm:$false
```

#COMMIT

```
$commitJob = Start-AzRecoveryServicesAsrCommitFailoverJob -ReplicationProtectedItem $rpi -Confirm:$false
```

#RE-PROTECT (I got this from https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/re-protect-different-data-store-azure-preview-m-alim-besari/?trk=public_profile_article_view)

```
$ReverseContainerMappingName = "crashconsistency-failback-containerpairing"
$reverseContainerMappingObject = GetAzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionContainerMapping -Name $ReverseContainerMappingName `
-ProtectionContainer $protectionContainer 

 Update-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionDirection -ReplicateAzureToVMware `
-Direction RecoveryToPrimary `
-Fabric $asrfabric `
-ProtectionContainerMapping $reverseContainerMappingObject `
-ReplicationProtectedItem $rpi  `
-LogStorageAccountId $StorageAccountId `
-DataStoreName $DatastoreName `
-ApplianceName $ApplianceName`
```

#ERROR:

> Update-AzRecoveryServicesAsrProtectionDirection : Operation failed.
> ClientRequestId: eb9fa552-74c6-4c8c-9d24-e07f044ef7d6-2024-02-23
> 22:10:19Z-Ps No appliance found with the name L1MGMT-ASR01.

When I go to the vault and to Site Recovery Infrastructure > For VMware & Physical Servers > ASR Replication Appliances ... I can see my appliance .. "L1MGMT-ASR01 (10.4.10.27)".
I have tried "L1MGMT-ASR01 (10.4.10.27)" and "L1MGMT-ASR01)".

I have looked for a command or combination of commands that would give me the appliance as an object, something like:

```
$appliance = get-asrAppliance
```

is there a way to get the appliance with powershell?
Am I actually doing this correctly?

For the failback steps I have

#PLANNED FAILOVER

```
Start-AzRecoveryServicesAsrPlannedFailoverJob -ReplicationProtectedItem $newReplicationProtectedItem -Direction RecoveryToPrimary -Confirm:$false
```

#COMMIT

```
Start-AzRecoveryServicesAsrCommitFailoverJob -ReplicationProtectedItem $newReplicationProtectedItem -Confirm:$false
```

#REPROTECT
I have nothing yet.

Any help on coding both re-protect steps would be fantastic.
Thanks.